# jQuery ajax call not triggered first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Every time I lose focus on the ID field the `alert("Start AJAX: " + EmplID);` is called but the AJAX calls are made two times: the second time the ID field loses focus and not at all the first time. All suggestions would be helpful.

```
$("#ID").focusout(function() {
    var EmplID = $(this).val();
    alert("Start AJAX: " + EmplID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "program_includes/Employee_help.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            value: 4,
            id: EmplID
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        parseScript(msg);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "program_includes/Customer_help.php",
            data: {
                value: 4,
                id: $("#Kundennummer").val(),
                Employee: "Yes"
            }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
            parseScript(msg);
            $("#Name").val($("#customers_Name").val());
        }).fail(function(msg) {
            alert("Fail2 : " + msg);
        });
    }).fail(function(msg) {
        alert("Fail1 : " + msg);
    });
});
```

Comment: My suggestion would be **not** to use `alert` for debugging. This is not 1997. Use a debugger for debugging. There's one built into your browser. That's always my recommendation, but particularly relevant here, as `alert` interferes with focus logic...

Comment: `console.log` would be better than `alert`

Comment: Seems to have solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from `T.J. Crowder`

> My suggestion would be not to use alert for debugging. This is not 1997. Use a debugger for debugging. There's one built into your browser. That's always my recommendation, but particularly relevant here, as alert interferes with focus logic..

Which is a pretty clear point to not use alert unless imo you are doing mobile development. You should be using console. So simply replace

```
 alert(); //badness
```

with

```
 console.info(); //goodness, look at the console
```

Then press `F12` in your browser and you'll see the logs in your console. Even the newest IE's have a JS console  now days.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's still the case in the most recent version of IE, but for earlier versions you have to press F12 before the code executed in order for the `console` object to exist.

Comment: Console works fine without having the console open in IE, atleast in IE10 and IE8. So since 2008 it has been working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of focusout, try using blur. The jQuery docs say as below:

```
The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses 
focus. This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of     
focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).
```

Or use event.stopPropagation() in focusout handler

Comment: That didn't change anything but removing the alerts solved the problem.
Thanks for your answer.